# reference current kube context in helm chart template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Bit of a helm novice here, in short I want to reference the current Kubernetes context within my helm chart template. Is this possible? Example:

if the upgrade was run via:

```
/var/jenkins_home/helm291 upgrade -i --kube-context Dev
```

And the template contained a deployment.yaml with the following:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
      env:
      {{- if contains "Dev" .Release.Kube_Context}}
```

Is there some variable I am missing that can check the Kube Context (aka replace Release.Kube_Context)? Am I approaching this the wrong way (specifying environment configuration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing it and it's also a bad practice to do it in the templates. Templates should be generic - you modify environment specific things in values.yaml files. You can use the --kube-context flag instead if you are running it from Jenkins

Comment: So, you're saying that values.yaml should declare the config for each environment, and when we run the command we override something (via --set) in the values.yaml to specify the environment to use?

Comment: We are running from jenkins, and the jenkins command does specify --kube-context. I'm just trying to figure out how we place the environment configuration in our helm charts such that the jenkins command can specify the environment and the proper configuration is then used

Comment: you are absolutely right. In order to configure environments, you would use something like values.dev.yaml or values.prod.yaml and keep environment specific configs in them. As a best practice, you also want to have secrets.dev.yaml and secrets.prod.yaml like files that contain sensitive data and encrypted (git-crypt or similar)

Answer (score 2):

You can export the context values you need and then execute helm, so they will be available as environmental vars.

For example, if you need the token access:

`export TOKEN=$(kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.users[?(@.name == "dev-user")].user.auth-provider.config.id-token}'); /var/jenkins_home/helm291 upgrade -i --kube-context Dev`

Comment: Upvoted because I believe this would work. But we don't have access to our Jenkins file unfortunately so I think we would have to go more of Adilet's approach