# Helm ingress auto generate the dns

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

**My goal** is to have a dns for my service without specifying the cluster dns in ingress.yaml or anywhere else because my chart is deployed in several different clusters with different dns’s.

In order to programmatically build my dns i need also a reference to my cluster url

I’m guessing this problem is already solved and I’m missing something basic.

The expected DNS: [service-name]-[namespace]-[cluster-url]

There are the following parameters, {{ .Release.Name }} == my-service-name
{{ .Release.Namespace }} == my kubernetes project name

Is there a release.clusterUrl built-in parameter to dynamically build my dns in ingress.yaml?
Or is there a simple flag that will build the dns in that structure?

Answer (score 0):

> goal is to have a dns for my service

As you're likely aware, [services can be accessed within the cluster by other services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) by means of `kube-dns`

If you're looking at allowing external access to your application via an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), and you want your FQDN to include the service name, then you will need to [specify routing based on host](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/bar"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: "*.foo.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/foo"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

Kubernetes itself can not provision DNS A records, which need to be setup externally to point to your clusters ingress ip. That DNS record can be supplied via your DNS provider (Think CloudFlare, Route 53, Power DNS etc).

**TLDR**: You will need to know the root domain you wish to host your service on, as you do not receive one by default. With some cloud providers, you will get a domain pointing to your kube api server, but this is not for serving public traffic on.

Please let me know what your expected `cluster-url` is, lest I'm missing some information that means the problem has been interpreted incorrectly

Comment: I dont know in advance the cluster url, the above is specifying foo.bar.com or *foo.com, I cant have the url of the cluster dns hard coded or partially hard coded. Is there a way to tell kuberentes to get it by it self?

Comment: Can you help me understand where you expect Kubernetes to retrieve the value from, and what an example of this value might be?

Comment: Yes, in helm I hold references to both service name and namespace, I expect from kubernetes to be able to provide a reference to the cluster url. When i helm install to a cluster url say x.y.z.com I expect to have a reference for example {{ .Release.Cluster }} that will evaluate to x.y.z.com and then I am able to build my full dns, {{.Release.ChartName }}-{{.Release.Namespace}}-{{ .Release.Cluster }} that way when Ill install the aame chart in 100 clusters I wont have to hardcode 100 cluster urls

Comment: > I expect from kubernetes to be able to provide a reference to the cluster url>
I think this is your issue, I understand that yo have provided an example of `x.y.z`, but do you have a tangible URL that Kubernetes has provided you with before? Perhaps through experimentation without helm, or do you have an equivalent way of retrieving that value with `kubectl`? As mentioned before, Kubernetes does not have a means of provisioning DNS records with other providers.

Comment: If you simply want to reference a cluster identifier in helm, you can pass through a value when deploying (When you deploy to each cluster, you will need to set your `kubectl` context up correctly, as such you will have some idea of the cluster you're deploying to), for example `helm install --set name=$(kubectl config current-context) myredis ./redis`. Or you can export a variable for use, such as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277169/reference-current-kube-context-in-helm-chart-template

Comment: That’s a workaround Im trying to avoid because it means that all of my chart consumers will need to know this secret convention, Im positive helm thought about this common use-case

Comment: If you're concerned about users installing your chart, then you most certainly can not predict the ingress dns record. It'll be different per user, depending on if they even want to expose your app externally. You need to let them decide this.
Helm is very aware of this, and includes an ingress when using `helm create <new-app-name>`. It is automatically disabled, and includes a place for users to specify their ingress hostname, and tls secrets.

Comment: i tend to disagree, its my chart, and its my rules, if you want to install my chart, you will know in advance that it opens a route from the cluster.
and with a simple use case of a dns composition, service-name + namespace + cluster url,  why is this so hard to absorb here?!

Comment: I've mentioned to you that there is no default cluster url, and you have failed to provide an example of one. To my understanding this is not possible, and I've shown you the way that Helm handles this with new projects.
There is an external dns provider, but even this needs top be configured: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns

I'll leave you be until you can explain exactly what you mean by 'default cluster url' because there isn't one.